# Xen / Grub2 - Domain 0 allocation causes boot panic

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, xen

Current setup / versions :

- Ubuntu Desktop 12.04
- Linux 3.2.0-32
- Xen 4.1-amd64
- Grub2

After following [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) to set up xen-hypervisor-amd64 and configuring grub2, when I reboot I get the below error:

```
(XEN) ********************
(XEN) Panic on CPU 0:
(XEN) Domain 0 allocation is too small for kernel image.
(XEN) ********************
```

My current /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=1024M"
```

Which results in the following menuentry after `update-grub`

```
submenu "Xen 4.1-amd64" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.1-amd64 and Linux 3.2.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root dfeb1395-8583-4bed-bc97-8f2317a7e9dd
        echo    'Loading Xen 4.1-amd64 ...'
        multiboot       /boot/xen-4.1-amd64.gz placeholder  dom0_mem=1024M
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-32-generic ...'
        module  /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic placeholder root=UUID=dfeb1395-8583-4bed-bc97-8f2317a7e9dd ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        module  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
}
```

I have tried just about every possible `dom0_mem=` value that I can think of including but not limited to: `dom0_mem=2097152`, `dom0_mem=min:1024M,max:1024M`, moving the entry to the vmlinuz module, and including it in the follow-up linux menuentry.

I don't know what to try next.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

With the addition of `dom0_max_vcpus=2`

```
multiboot /boot/xen-4.1-amd64.gz placeholder dom0_mem=1024M dom0_max_vcpus=2
```

I get the same boot panic. But interestingly in the info displayed at boot it continues to display "Brought up 4 CPUs".

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: You could try the different options for the "acpi" Xen parameter. It could be that information from ACPI about memory regions is incorrect/incomplete...

Comment: I tried [every acpi option](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-Configuring_the_Xen_kernel_boot_parameters.html) with no change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the dom0_mem that's an issue here. I think we're talking about space needed to load the kernel and initrd in memory into special area reserved by Xen.

Could  it be that the initrd and/or vmlinuz are abnormally large. You could also try to reduce the number of CPUs available to dom0 (`dom0_max_vcpus=2` for instance).

Comment: xen-4.1-amd64.gz is 715K, all my initrd and vmlinuz are less than 5M.  See above about CPU's.